# Click a check box and table row is not synchronized

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

How can I enable the button when user checks the checkbox itself? Currently the button will be enabled when user clicks on the table row(clickable row).

```
var btn = $("#btn");    
btn.attr("disabled","disabled");

$("#table tbody").on("click",".clickable-row", function (e) {   
    if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox') {
        $(':checkbox', this).trigger('click');

        if($(':checkbox', this).is(":checked") == true){
            btn.removeAttr('disabled');
            $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="chk" value="'+$(':checkbox', this).val()+'" />');              

        } else {
            btn.attr("disabled", !$(':checkbox', this).is(":checked"));
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Remove the `if (e.target.type !== 'checkbox')` condition

Comment: @Nicolas Filotto when I remove that part, I cannot check the checkbox at all. Only can check through clickable row. I want to make both works

Comment: can you share also the html?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var btn = $("#btn");    
btn.attr("disabled","disabled");

$("#table tbody").on("click", function (e) {
    var thisCheckbox = $(this).find('input:checkbox');
    var thisTd = $(this).find('td');

    if(thisCheckbox.is(":checked") || thisTd.is(e.target)){
        if($(this).find('td').is(e.target))
        {
            thisCheckbox.prop('checked', true);
        }
        btn.removeAttr('disabled');
        $('form').append('<input type="hidden" name="chk" value="'+$(':checkbox', this).val()+'" />');  
    }else{
        if(thisTd.is(e.target))
        {
            thisCheckbox.prop('checked', false);
        }
        btn.attr("disabled", !$(':checkbox', this).is(":checked"));
    }

});
```

Comment: this only works when I click the checkbox(enable the button). when I click the table row, nothing happen(the button remains disabled)

Comment: this does not work. when i click a checkbox, it will check all checkboxes available in the column